# Instantiating unique bash instances with their own PID from a single parent array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I was given a command "ChanDataStream_Sim" (on a linux box) that I need to run against 40 channels simultaneously. The command once executed runs indefinitely until someone manually kills the PID. Moreover the command will halt if interrupted or the session ended. A new dedicated PuTTy session would need to be launched for each channel we want to test.

What I would like to do is instantiate an instance of the command with EACH iteration of channel in my array. Essentially if I list 30 channels in my array, I'd like to see 30 instances (with their own PID) of the command line running. I want to avoid having the engineer open 40 PuTTy sessions just to run the thing or having to craft 40 tiny scripts if at all possible.

Desired outcome:

```
PID      User
1112     ChanDataStream_Sim+ <--- For Channel 3002
1113     ChanDataStream_Sim+ <--- For Channel 1001
1114     ChanDataStream_Sim+ <--- For Channel 4003
1115     ChanDataStream_Sim+ <--- For any additional channels in the array
```

Here's what I wrote so far.

```
#bash
#!/bin/bash

# all the channels to simulate data flow against.
channels=(3002 1001 4003)

# how fast the simulated data should hit the channel
priority=(IDLE REALTIME HIGH)

# selecting one of the 225 daemons available for the process to run against
objserv=(83 82 81)

length=${#channels[@]}
for (( i=0; i<$length; i++ ))
do

# running the command with the requisite channel variables
ChanDataStream_Sim ${channels[$i]} -d -p ${priority[$i]} -s ${objserv[$i]}
done
```

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: kick the `ChanDataStream_Sim` call into the background by appending `&` on the end of the line? eg, `ChanDataStream_Sim .... &`; though you may not be able to implement some of your other requirements, eg, *Moreover the command will halt if interrupted or the session ended.*

Comment: Look into using a tool like GNU Parallel.

Comment: @markp-fuso It worked beautifully! Huge thanks for the suggestion! I was able to spawn dozens of the same command each with their own PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: This snippet creates iterations of the embedded command based on the number of channels in the array

```
#bash
#!/bin/bash
# Testing Channels: 1001, 2001, 2004

# Setting up my channels and openChan_sim controls
channels=(3002 1001 4003)
priority=(REALTIME REALTIME REALTIME)
objserv=(83 82 81)

# Get the length of one of the arrays
length=${#channels[@]}

# Function to perform the iteration in a subshell
perform_iteration() {
    local index=$1
    openChan_sim ${channels[$index]} -d -p ${priority[$index]} -s ${objserv[$index]}"
}

# Loop through the channels and create subshell instances
for ((i=0; i<length; i++))
do
    (perform_iteration "$i") &
done
wait
```

Comment: Your quotes on the last line in perform_iteration are unbalanced, which is why the syntax highlighting is off past that point.

Comment: Also, there's no reason for the parens -- `foo &` itself already creates a subshell. `(foo) &` is making `foo` a grandchild rather than a child for no good reason.

Comment: (also, you're missing some quoting -- `openChan_sim "${channels[$index]}" -d -p "${priority[$index]}" -s "${objserv[$index]}"` will give you better error messages / more predictable behavior if you ever have an invalid index value passed, values for an argument that contain whitespace or glob characters, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, excellent point. Tried it with quotes which made error tracking much more informative and predictable. It works flawlessly regardless of length of array. I just had to becareful not to kill the parent session or else all my child subshells would die as well